# VBA hide lmage in module

Tags: excel, vba, image

I need to hide a logo in excel. I want this logo to be displayed in excel sheet 1 if its not there. I can not hide this in any sheet and call it. Is there a way i can hide the logo in the module and show it if its not found on sheet 1? I need to open this file in multiple computers. Pls help

Comment: You can place an image in a UserForm and save it with the form. I don't think this is very practical, but to be honest I don't understand your use case either.

Comment: Ok. I am developing VBA programs for different clients. I need to add company logo and web address in the first sheet. I need the logo to be there even if the user deletes it from the sheet. Dont want to hide it in a hidden sheet. Simple

Answer (score 0):

**An idea**: you can position the image in a cell and lock it with a password.

[image]